# How can I make vim "command mode" the default mode for terminal

Tags: mac, terminal, vi

I use vim commands in my terminal.. 
But by default, the mode when I open up terminal is the "insert mode". 
Is it possible to enter in "command mode" when I open a terminal session?

Answer (score 2):

No there in no way to start your terminal in command mode.

The `set keymap` setting is used to customize the keymap within terminal. A line with `set keymap vi-command` means that mappings below that line apply to command mode; a line with `set keymap vi-insert` means that mappings below that line apply to insert mode. For more details see: http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Use_vi_shortcuts_in_terminal

But starting from bash version 4.3 you can change your prompt to highlight which mode you are currently in by putting `set show-mode-in-prompt on` in your `~/.inputrc` file. This with put either `(ins)` or `(cmd)` at the start of your prompt. You can further customize it by using command:

`set vi-cmd-mode-string "\1\e[1;31m\2(cmd)\1\e[0m\2"` -- will give light red color

`set vi-ins-mode-string "\1\e[1;35m\2(ins)\1\e[0m\2"` -- will give light purple color

You can pick any of the following color by their ANSI codes:

`Black            \e[0;30m
Blue             \e[0;34m
Green            \e[0;32m
Cyan             \e[0;36m
Red              \e[0;31m
Purple           \e[0;35m
Brown            \e[0;33m
Gray             \e[0;37m
Dark Gray        \e[1;30m
Light Blue       \e[1;34m
Light Green      \e[1;32m
Light Cyan       \e[1;36m
Light Red        \e[1;31m
Light Purple     \e[1;35m
Yellow           \e[1;33m
White            \e[1;37m`

Answer (score 0):

**Readline Init File, `~/.inputrc`**

Depending on the command(s) you run to get your console in the desired mode, just add that line in `~/.inputrc`. This should be sufficient.

If `~/.inputrc` does not exist, you can create it without worries.

A line with `set keymap vi-command` sets your Terminal to' command mode'; a line with `set keymap vi-insert` your Terminal to 'insert mode'.

Comment: I don't want to "run" any command. 
Right now I have 'set editing-mode vi' in my ~/.inputrc.
So in my terminal if I press 'Esc', it goes from command mode to the input mode..  
What I want is, when i open terminal, it should go to command mode automatically, and I should be able to switch to vim mode when I press 'i'.
How can that be achieved?

Comment: `set keymap vi-command`

Comment: That doesn't work.